# Trouble with prompt boxes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I am having trouble with my assignment. I was told to create a simple "Grade Calculator" using prompt boxes It was fairly easy to make this "Grade Calculator" but the problem I am facing is that I was told to create this "Grade Calculator" in a manner that if someone fails in a subject they fail in all subjects(No Grade) and if someone scores passing marks(50) on all subjects they should be able to see their grade so the problem is that I get the overall result two times like if someone passes in all subjects it works just fine but if someone fails in one subject it shows that the person has failed(NO GRADE) and then shows that they have passed and shows their grade. I hope I explained it correctly.
Thanks
P.S: I can only use prompt boxes and sorry for my bad grammar/punctuation.

```
<!doctype html> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Untitled Document</title> </head> <body> <script>
var sub1 = parseInt( prompt("Insert Your sub1 Marks") );
var sub2 = parseInt( prompt("Insert Your sub2 Marks") );
var sub3 = parseInt( prompt("Insert Your sub3 Marks") );
var sub4 = parseInt( prompt("Insert Your sub4 Marks") );
var sub5 = parseInt( prompt("Insert Your sub5 Marks") );
var tot = parseInt(sub1+sub2+sub3+sub4+sub5);
 var per = parseInt(((tot)/500)*100)
 alert('Total: ' + tot + ' Out Of 500');
 alert('Percentage: ' + per + '%' );
 if(sub1<=49){
 alert('Fail --NO GRADE--');
 }
 if(sub2<=49){
 alert('Fail --NO GRADE--');
 }
 if(sub3<=49){
 alert('Fail --NO GRADE--');
 }
 if(sub4<=49){
 alert('Fail --NO GRADE--');
 }
 if(sub5<=49){
 alert('Fail --NO GRADE--');
 }
 else if(per >=50 && per <60) {
 alert('Pass --D Grade--');
 }
 else if(per >=60 && per <70) {
 alert('Pass --C Grade--');
 }
 else if(per >=70 && per <80) {
 alert('Pass --B Grade--');
 }
 else if(per >=80 && per <90) {
 alert('Pass --A Grade--');
 }
 else if(per >=90 && per <100) {
 alert('Pass --A* Grade--');
 }
</script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: I would combine all fail checks into one if statement `if(sub1<=49 || sub2<=49 ...)` then your else if will work correctly.

Comment: it's because your first `else` is an alternative only for the test `if(sub5<=49){`, if any of the cases before are true and this one false, the first ones will be executed and the alternative to the last one too. One way to solve this would be to add an `else` before all cases starting with this one `if(sub2<=49){` or even better with CrnaStena's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you use to work with JavaScript, to test your solutions, but JSFiddle is great. Here is your working [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/3pmodqw8/).

```
if(sub1<=49 || sub2<=49 || sub3<=49 || sub4<=49 || sub5<=49){
 alert('Fail --NO GRADE--');
 }
 else if(per >=50 && per <60) {
```

Another way is to use SO code snippets, see below.

```js
var sub1 = parseInt( prompt("Insert Your sub1 Marks") );
var sub2 = parseInt( prompt("Insert Your sub2 Marks") );
var sub3 = parseInt( prompt("Insert Your sub3 Marks") );
var sub4 = parseInt( prompt("Insert Your sub4 Marks") );
var sub5 = parseInt( prompt("Insert Your sub5 Marks") );
var tot = parseInt(sub1+sub2+sub3+sub4+sub5);
 var per = parseInt(((tot)/500)*100)
 alert('Total: ' + tot + ' Out Of 500');
 alert('Percentage: ' + per + '%' );
 if(sub1<=49 || sub2<=49 || sub3<=49 || sub4<=49 || sub5<=49){
 alert('Fail --NO GRADE--');
 }
 else if(per >=50 && per <60) {
 alert('Pass --D Grade--');
 }
 else if(per >=60 && per <70) {
 alert('Pass --C Grade--');
 }
 else if(per >=70 && per <80) {
 alert('Pass --B Grade--');
 }
 else if(per >=80 && per <90) {
 alert('Pass --A Grade--');
 }
 else if(per >=90 && per <100) {
 alert('Pass --A* Grade--');
 }
```